# Redirect not .html url to .html in joomla

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, router

I need to redirect non .html url to .html url via htaccess.

For example my url is `http://domainname.com/contact-us` and `http://domainname.com/contact-us.html` both url opening. But my requirement is to redirect `http://domainname.com/contact-us` to `http://domainname.com/contact-us.html`

I am trying following code but it still not working at all.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QEQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L,R]
```

This will first check if the file (requested uri) exists and is a regular html file, if it exists , then the rule will redirect **/file** to **/file.html** .

Comment: please define "its not working" . What error are you gettin with this code

Comment: I have placed this code as it is but it is not working with our pages. All page are open with non .html and with .html